# Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'CGPDFPage'

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode8, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

How do I fix this?

```
//Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'CGPDFPage'
CGContextDrawPDFPage(obContext, nil)
```

Using **Xcode 8** and have not converted to swift3 syntax yet.

Comment: That function takes a `CGContext` and a `CGPDFPage`.  What are you expecting it to do passing `nil` to the second argument?

Comment: I'm expecting to pass nil

Comment: But what do you think that method is going to do if you pass it `nil`?  It doesn't make any sense.  Why call it all if you want to pass it `nil`?